# Why do these two instances of a script perform differently?

Tags: performance, matlab, optimization, multidimensional-array

I have 2 instances of an algorithm I'm implementing, and I want it to be as fast as possible, because it will be part of a routine that I need to repeat many times.

The idea is the following: I have a `n` by `n` by `m` matrix (call it `c`) and based on it I have to create an `m` by `n` matrix (call it `z`). Each row of `z` is the result of multiplying the previous row by the corresponding `n` by `n` slice of `c`, and normalizing.

I had the idea that in matlab is always best to vectorize the code and avoid loops if possible, so I thought the first approach was the fastest I could think of. But it turns out the second implementation is about a 15% faster. Could anyone explain me why? Also, could you tell me if I can do better than the second option?

Here are dummy versions of the two scripts (close enough for illustration purposes)

Script 1

```
clear all

x = -5:.02:5;
w = 1:.02:11;
t(1,1,:) = w;

n = length(x);
m = length(w);


z      = zeros(m,n);
z(1,:) = exp(-x.^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi);    

a = bsxfun(@times,x,t);
b = bsxfun(@minus,a,x');
c = exp(-bsxfun(@rdivide,b.^2,2*t));

for i = 2:m

    z(i,:) = z(i-1,:)*squeeze(c(:,:,i));
    z(i,:) = z(i,:)/trapz(x,z(i,:));

end
```

Script 2

```
clear all

x = -5:.02:5;
t = 1:.02:11;

n = length(x);
m = length(t);


z      = zeros(m,n);
z(1,:) = exp(-x.^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi);

for i=2:m

    c = exp(-(bsxfun(@minus,x*t(i),x')).^2/(2*t(i)));
    z(i,:) = z(i-1,:)*c;
    z(i,:) = z(i,:)/trapz(x,z(i,:));

end
```

I didn't expect the line in Script 1

```
z(i,:) = z(i-1,:)*squeeze(c(:,:,i));
```

to be as slow as it is.

Comment: You don't need that `squeezing`, do you? You can probably save some there.

Comment: True. I tried removing it and doesn't make any difference tho.

Answer (score 1):

Indexing into the ndim arrays could be expensive when done iteratively. So, we could use a *scratchpad-variable* to avoid that. Thus, we could modify `script #2` to something like this -

```
z      = zeros(m,n);
tmp    = exp(-x.^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi);
z(1,:) = tmp;
for i=2:m
    tmp = tmp*exp(-(bsxfun(@minus,x*t(i),x')).^2/(2*t(i)));
    tmp = tmp/trapz(x,tmp);
    z(i,:) = tmp;
end
```

The `tmp` variable is that scratchpad-variable used here. Also, we are feeding in the `bsxfun(@minus` result that we were storing as `c` earlier directly into the next step.

Runtime test -

With the inputs :

```
x = -5:.04:5;
t = 1:.04:11;
```

Timings :

```
--------------------- With Script #2
Elapsed time is 0.571562 seconds.
--------------------- With Optimized Script
Elapsed time is 0.478028 seconds.
```

So, some marginal improvement there.

Comment: I see, clever! Thank you!
My hope was to really cut down on the evaluation of `c` but I guess there's  not much more to do there.

Comment: @J.R.C. Yeah finding the closed form of that recursive form doesn't seem straight-forward given the `trapz` calculations involved there.

Comment: I think for it to work is necessary to add a line tho:

`tmp = tmp/trapz(x,tmp);`

`z(i,:) = tmp;`

Comment: what if I didn't have the `trapz`?

Comment: Ah you meant finding an actual analytical closed expression @divakar ?

Comment: @J.R.C. Yes, exactly!

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible... That's the main issue :P
I'm still very intrigued why applying bsxfun over the third dimension is slower than just looping tho. Could it be the transfering ´c´many times inside the loop in script is expensive? @divakar

Comment: @J.R.C. Yeah I tried a bit and seems like I have to give up on finding the closed form even without the `trapz` step. On the `script #1` being slower, I would think it has to do with `c` being a huge 3D array there and the memory transfers needed is offseting it, whereas with `script#2`, there its `2D` and re-used sooner.